# How can I cut part of a string out and insert it into another string? (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, string, html

I need to retrieve an html page and then isolate part of the code.

First, I have a large bit of html. I need to find this:

```
<div class="XP_points">Anything here.</div>
```

and have

```
<div class="XP_points">9,775</div>
```

put in another string. I can take it from there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
            string text= sourcetext
            text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(text , "XP_points""">")(1)
            string sig1 = text
            sig1 = sig1.IndexOf("<", 1)
            text = text.Remove(sig1, text.Length - sig1)

            sourcetext=sourcetext.Replace(text,"9,775")
```

Comment: Why are you using System.Text.RegularExpressions, if you **aren't using** any regular expressions with it?

Comment: @druciferre i think i am finding first instance of "XP_points""">" in text using regular expressions and splitting the text from "XP_points""">" to "<"

Comment: My point is that you're using plain text with regular expression functions when you could have just used the Replace() and Split() functions.

Comment: Also, in his example, if "Anything here." occurs anywhere else in the source text, it will replace that too.

Comment: And... Even further, if `XP_points">` isn't anywhere in the source text, then your code will cause an index out of bounds error.

Comment: @druciferre Actually, that is likely to happen. XP_Points and other specific divs only show up on certain pages this application is parsing. At the moment, the application would find

`<div class="XP_points">9,775</div>`
and `<div class="gold_points">9,805</div>`

and output, to two separate strings (these are handled by different sections of the code atm)
`9,775` and `9,805`.
This is referring to a live-action style game, which has about twenty different locations. XP_points and gold_points only show up if you have actually visited this physical location.

Comment: @druciferre (again). It'll check for certain identifying aspects (such as presence of these specific divs) before trying to extract various strings. Using a couple of If then else elseif statements, (and one or two exception handlers), it'll execute different code based on the situation.

Comment: @druciferre man read his question. XP_points"> is actually the part of source string. Obviously he has to first check for these div are there in his html source.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which exposes rich functionality for interrogating and mutating HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Regular Expressions to search for the data and replace it with what you want.

Start here for using regular expressions in VB.Net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.item.aspx#Y0

And check out this for matching HTML tags in Regular Expression example

http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Comment: I would post the code for you, but I don't have VB.Net installed on any of my PCs at home, and I refuse to post code I haven't compiled and verified to work.